# SKPSMTPMessage Library for iOS 7

Tags: email, ios7, smtp

Has anybody had any luck using the SKPSMTPMessage Library with iOS 7?

When I compile I keep getting ARMv7 errors, just wondering if anyone found a work around for this yet?

Thanks!